# NameError: global name '' is not defined , but differences

Tags: python, module

According to you know, When user get the following error:

```
NameError: global name 'A_NAME' is not defined
```

user probabely made two mistake.

consider the following code:

```
from ui.interface.interface import *
self.interfaceCodesConstructor = ui.interface.interface.InterfaceCodes()
```

1. if user delete ui.interface.interface from line 2
2. user forgot import module.

Above code is belong to me.Unfortuenately, i get the error:

```
NameError: global name 'ui' is not defined
```

for second line.

my dir structure is true:

```
main.py 
|
|
ui--intreface--interface.py
\
 \materliasFrame.py
```

**Notes:** I have `__init__.py` for each dir.

**Question:** Where's problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't `import ui.interface.interface` - you asked python to import all of the functions from `ui.interface.interface`.

So you can simply say

```
self.interfaceCodesConstructor = InterfaceCodes()
```

or change your import statement.

---

To clarify, you will either have

```
import ui.interface.interface
self.interfaceCodesConstructor = ui.interface.interface.InterfaceCodes()
```

or

```
from ui.interface.interface import *
self.interfaceCodesConstructor = InterfaceCodes()
```

Comment: i just import line and put `self.interfaceCodesConstructor = ui.interface.interface.InterfaceCodes()` , Thank you.

Comment: if possible edit line `self.interfaceCodesConstructor = InterfaceCodes()` to `self.interfaceCodesConstructor = ui.interfac.interface.InterfaceCodes()`

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow what you're asking.  I will update my post to be clear.